# Javascript prime number error?

Tags: javascript, primes

Could someone please help me find the error in this code? I'm reading through what I came up with and it logically makes sense to me each step of the way, but it's not producing the desired result. At the end I test calling the function with 6.

```
function is_prime(num) {
    if (isNaN(num)) return false;
    var numFactors = 0;
    for (i=1; i<=num; i++) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
        numFactors += 1;
        }
        return numFactors;
    }
    if (numFactors === 2) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

console.log(is_prime(6));
```

Comment: a tip instead looping till `num` you can loop it till it's square root `Math.sqrt (num)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the function from inside the `forloop`.

So it never hits the other statements

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/vMYKY/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are having is that you are potentially returning your `numFactors` too early:

```
for (i=1; i<=num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
    numFactors += 1;
    }
    return numFactors;
}
```

Here, you are returning the numFactors at the end of your first loop, so it never actually finishes the full test.

Answer (score 0):

Counting factors is not a right approach -

use this -

```
function is_prime(num) {
    if (isNaN(num)) return false;
    var k = Math.sqrt(num);

    for (i=2; i<=k; i++) {
       if(num%i===0)return false;
    }
    return false;
 }

 console.log(is_prime(6));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are stepping through all numbers from 1 to num for factrorization you might as well pick them up as factors and get a bit more out of your function:

```
function fact(num) {
    if (isNaN(num)) return false;
    var Factors=[];
    for (i=1; i<=num; i++) {
     if (num % i == 0)  Factors.push(i)
    }
    return Factors
}

console.log('factors: '+fact(27));
console.log('is prime: '+fact(27).length===2);
```